# Keyboard stopped working on Intel x86 Android emulator after upgrading to ADT 20

Tags: android, android-emulator

I mean I can't type from my laptop keyboard into android emulator anymore.
Virtual and on-screen keyboards are working fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Tools version 20. I had to Edit the AVD to add an option as follows:

- From Eclipse, Go to AVD Mananger.
- Select the particular AVD and click on Edit
- Go to the Hardware section, click on New.
- Select the Property Name : Keyboard Support
- By default, it is added with a value of 'no'. Just click on the value column and change it to 'yes'.
- Click on Edit AVD again.

This will add a property hw.keyboard=yes in config.ini file for the AVD. And it should work fine from there.

Comment: It is suggested to recreate your emulators after upgrading the tools to version 20.  internet may not work in android browsers after updation and you may face other issues too.  Just delete the existing avds and create it again.

Comment: Try to use the feature of adding property in (i.e hw.keyboard=yes) from avd manager if you use custom skins instead of builtin skins.

Comment: Now I must ask, why on earth would the default value of something I manually added is 'no'. If I wanted 'no keyboard' I wouldn't add keyboard support in the first place!