# Inputs not working in Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am using Phonegap 1.9.0 in Android 4.1 with the following simplified `index.html` page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>                
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="somethings"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

The app comes up fine, but when I give focus to the input and try to give it text, nothing gets entered.

The OS acts as if I am pressing keys (on the virtual keyboard) because it is suggesting spelling corrections and the keyboard UI responds... but nothing makes it into the input field.

What am I missing?

Comment: is there any css that you did not post?

Comment: No.  This is the only code in my `index.html` file in order to reproduce it.  I should also add that if I go to the browser in the emulator and open a page with an input, it works fine.  It is just in my super-simple Phonegap app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in PhoneGap 1.9.0, and has been fixed for the upcoming 2.0 version

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/rEo8IjPY28Q/SOUWO7x6MfAJ

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines of script in html file and try:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ disableCaching: false });
    Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Hardware keyboard support explicitly enabled for your Emulator AVD. Please refer to this question for details : [Keyboard stoped working on Intel x86 Android emulator after upgrading to ADT 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259888/keyboard-stoped-working-on-intel-x86-android-emulator-after-upgrading-to-adt-20/11259966#11259966)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please type with softkey, instead of emulator keys.  It should work.

Emulator keys may not work some times. What you can try is add "Keyboard support" while creating emulator.

AVD manager -- > select your emulator -- Edit .. Hardware section

```
    click New button select "Keyboard support' from property dropdown.
    double click on no to show yes/no drop down and set it to YES.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue - I use Titanium .

I'm on an Ubutnu, so this is how I fixed it: Titanium -> Window menu -> AVD Manager -> highlighted my emulator I want to fix -> click "Edit..." button -> at the bottom, there is a "Hardware" section -> click "New.." -> then find "Keyboard Support" option in the dropdown -> Hit OK -> under the "Hardware" section again, highlight the "Keyboard support" item you just added and in the "Value" column change it to "yes" -> click off or click on another property list in the "hardware" box (this seems to apply the change) -> click "edit AVD" button.

This seemed to fix it for me.